# How to use remote hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I have a Hadoop cluster deployed, and the client MapReduce program is running on another machine. How can I use that cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you have you have your jars in a client machine install hadoop-client packages in that machine and have configuration details of cluster in conf folder so that you can trigger your jobs from client machine into remote cluster

Comment: So if I installed both the cluster and client manually, (by extracting tar file into local file system and set environment variables), should I use cluster's conf files on the client machine? And there are many conf files (xml), are they all needed or just some of them?